# Using event from button 1 in button 2

Tags: c#, events, button

I have 2 buttons. I am trying to use event from button 1 into button 2 so they both do the same thing.
So by clicking 2, button 1 get clicked also. I am doing this actually from menu strip item but I suppose it has the same principle. I just don't want to have duplicated code. I thought that button1.Click() would work, but apparently it doesn't. How could I do this?

**Simplified example:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count += 1;
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count += 1;
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
}
```

-- EDIT --

I am using a class diagram which doesn't show any additional methods that would/should do this. Need to stick to the class diagram.

Comment: is there any problem if you create a function() and use it

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Put the code that's in both events into its own method and call that.
2. Make a single _click method and set it as both button's event handler.
3. You could call `button2_Click` from `button1_click` **(i advise against this one)**.

---

### 1

```
private IncrementAndDisplay()
{
    count += 1;
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IncrementAndDisplay();
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IncrementAndDisplay();
}
```

---

### 2

```
// Change both button's clicked events to use this method in the IDE, or in code.
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count += 1;
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
}
```

---

### 3

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2_Click(sender, e); // Bad!
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count += 1;
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
}
```

Comment: I just edited my OP saying that I do not see any extra method that should be there. Why is your 3rd option bad?

Comment: Then go for option 2. Option 3 is bad because if `button1_Click` and `button2_Click` are far apart and you look at `button1_click` it's not obvious what's going on at all. Given that this is [tag:homework] i believe they're looking for you to do #2.

Comment: I don't fully understand how number 2 works. I must have one button named btnEnter and other tsmiEnter. Using same name isn't an option.

Comment: You don't need to use the same name. The name of the method `button1_Click` could be anything. In the form designer, click on your button. Then click the events section in properties. There, find the `Click` event. You'll see that button1_click and button2_click are both selectable.

Comment: If you have the button selected in the forms designer, look at the properties panel (bottom right by default). Look for an icon that looks like a lightning bolt. You'll then get a list of all available events for the button. Find the `Click` one.

Comment: I lied, After reading the MSDN website it told me where are events. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever button1 does put in a separate method, and call that method from both buttons,
it is better to separate the code and then you don't duplicate anything.

What you offered creates an unnatural dependency between the buttons that should not exist.

About your class diagram, if it is a private method then it should not matter.

Comment: That is exactly why I am having this problem. The second button is a button from menu strip which, as I am asked to do, has to enter information provided. I though just by calling a button 1 should be enough.

Comment: The guy who grades is being an ******* when grading.

Comment: then like @George Duckett offered, change the code to make both buttons call the same "click" method. (Option 2).

Maybe you should check with your grader whether or not adding a private method matters. It usually doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a separate function/method to handle the action and then have both button handlers call that function:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doTheThing();
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   doTheThing();
}

private void doTheThing()
{
    count += 1;
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
}
```